# Inserting 2.55 gives 2.5499999999999998

Tags: sql-server

When I insert `2.55` into a table with a `float` type column and retrieve it afterwards, I get `2.5499999999999998`.

Here's what I've done using sqlcmd:

```
CREATE DATABASE DB;
GO

USE DB;
GO

CREATE TABLE test (floating_col FLOAT);
GO

INSERT INTO test (floating_col) VALUES (2.55);
GO

(1 rows affected)

SELECT * FROM test;
GO

floating_col            
------------------------
      2.5499999999999998

(1 rows affected)
```

This is the version I am using:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64) Aug 22 2017 17:04:49 
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS)
```

Why is it not `2.55` after insertion?

Comment: Use decimal instead of float because *Floating point data is approximate; therefore, not all values in the data type range can be represented exactly.*

Comment: I Got 2.55 in  Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 Whats your sql version?

Comment: In SSMS, i get 2.55 against 2012, 2017 and 2019, @mhd.cs, but if you use `sqlcmd`, as the OP has done, you get `2.5499999999999998`. This is due to the different ways that presentation layers interpret floating point values.

Comment: @Maeh , is there any reason you haven't patched your SQL Server in the over 2 years? You're running the RTM version, which has known security vulnerabilities; for example Spectre and Meltdown that were patched in early 2018.

Answer (score 1):

The `FLOAT` data type is not a precise data type. If you need exact precision then you should be using `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC`.

```
1> CREATE TABLE test (floating_col DECIMAL(18,2));
2> go
1> INSERT INTO test (floating_col) VALUES (2.55);
2> go

(1 rows affected)
1> SELECT * FROM test;
2> go
floating_col            
------------------------
2.55
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to use the data type 'real' in place of the data type 'float' there will be no such problems.

Comment: `real` and `float` are the same underlying datatype. `real` is just a synonym for `float(24)`. As the OP hasn't defined the precision of their `float`, the default precision value was used (`53`). [float and real (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE DATABASE DB1;
GO

USE DB1;
GO

CREATE TABLE test1 (floating_col REAL);
GO

INSERT INTO test1 (floating_col) VALUES (2.55);
GO

(1 rows affected)

SELECT * FROM test1;
GO

floating_col            
------------------------
      2.55

(1 rows affected)
```

Comment: An explanation, what the posted code does and how this addresses the problem in the question, rarely fails to improve an answer.

Comment: This code will help you add any fractional number and get exactly as you added. For example. If you added 1.4554 you get 1.4554 or 121.1 you get 121.1 ;. And if you want to add 12.6689 and you want to get 12.6689, DECIMAL (18,2) will not help you.